# Using/Configuring Symfony security component

Tags: php, security, symfony

Am attempting to configure security using Symfony's security component in a custom PHP applications. I have everything wired right down to HTTP Kernel and all the authentication and authorization goods making use of in-memory user provider.

However, when I access protected URL I get the following error "A Token was not found in the SecurityContext". My understanding is that if their is not Token Symfony should redirect to configured login screen.

The other funny thing is that when I configured access map with any entry to require HTTPs, it changes protocols and redirects to /login.

Not sure If any one has working example, Silex and Symfony security bundle seem rather complex to distill.

Current configurations using Dependency-injection

```
        ##Authentication 
    $this->container->setParameter( "anonymous_key", uniqid() );
    $this->container->register( "password.encoder.pbkd", "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder");
    $this->container->register( "provider.inmemory", "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\InMemoryUserProvider" );
    $this->container->register( "user.checker", "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserChecker" );

    $this->container->register( "encoder.factory", "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactory")
        ->addArgument( ["Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User"=>new Reference("password.encoder.pbkd")] );

    $this->container->register( "authentication.provider.daoauth","Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\DaoAuthenticationProvider")
        ->addArgument(new Reference( "provider.inmemory" ))
        ->addArgument(new Reference( "user.checker" ))
        ->addArgument( "secured" )
        ->addArgument(new Reference( "encoder.factory" ));

    $this->container->register( "authentication.provider.anonymousauth","Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\AnonymousAuthenticationProvider")
        ->addArgument("%anonymous_key%");

    $this->container->register( "authentication.provider.manager","Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\AuthenticationProviderManager")
        ->addArgument( [ new Reference("authentication.provider.daoauth"), new Reference("authentication.provider.anonymousauth")] );

    ##Authorization
    $this->container->register( "voter.authenticated", "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\AuthenticatedVoter")
        ->addArgument( new Reference("authentication.trust.resolver") );

    $this->container->register( "rolehierarchy", "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleHierarchy")
        ->addArgument( ["ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN"=>["ROLE_ADMIN","ROLE_USER"]]);
    $this->container->register( "voter.rolehierarchy", "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\RoleHierarchyVoter")
        ->addArgument( new Reference( "rolehierarchy" ));

    $this->container->register( "authorization.access_decision.manager","Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AccessDecisionManager")
        ->addArgument(  [ new Reference("voter.rolehierarchy"), new Reference( "voter.authenticated" ) ] );

    ##Context
    $this->container->register( "security.context", "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext")
        ->addArgument( new Reference("authentication.provider.manager") )
        ->addArgument( new Reference("authorization.access_decision.manager") );


    #Firewall, Access and Controls  

    ###RequestMatcher
    $this->container->register("backend.requestmatcher", "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestMatcher")
        ->addArgument("%backend_prefix%");

    ###AccessMap
    $this->container->register( "security.accessmap", "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\AccessMap")
        ->addMethodCall("add", [new Reference("backend.requestmatcher"), ["ROLE_ADMIN"] ] );

    ###HTTPUtils
    $this->container->register( "http.utils", "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils")
        ->addArgument( new Reference( "symfony.url.generator" ) )
        ->addArgument( new Reference( "symfony.url.matcher" ) );

    ###Session Strategy
    $this->container->register( "session.strategy.authentication", "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Session\SessionAuthenticationStrategy")
        ->addArgument( SessionAuthenticationStrategy::MIGRATE );

    ###Resolvers
    $this->container->register( "authentication.trust.resolver", "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\AuthenticationTrustResolver")
        ->addArgument("Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AnonymousToken")
        ->addArgument("Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\RememberMeToken");      

    ###EntryPoint
    $this->container->register( "entrypoint.formauth", "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\EntryPoint\FormAuthenticationEntryPoint")
        ->addArgument( new Reference("http.kernel") )
        ->addArgument( new Reference("http.utils") )
        ->addArgument( "/login" );

    ###Listener
    #### 
    $this->container->register("security.exception.listener", "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ExceptionListener")
        ->addArgument(new Reference( "security.context" ) )
        ->addArgument(new Reference( "authentication.trust.resolver" ))
        ->addArgument( new Reference( "http.utils") )
        ->addArgument( "testing" )
        ->addArgument( null )
        ->addArgument( null )
        ->addArgument( null )
        ->addArgument( new Reference("monologger.security") );      

    $this->container->register("security.channel.listener", "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ChannelListener")
        ->addArgument( new Reference( "security.accessmap" ))
        ->addArgument( new Reference( "entrypoint.formauth" ))
        ->addArgument( new Reference( "monologger.security" ));

    $this->container->register("security.anonymous.listener", "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\AnonymousAuthenticationListener")
        ->addArgument(new Reference( "security.context" ) )
        ->addArgument( "" )
        ->addArgument( new Reference( "monologger.security" ));

    $this->container->register("security.logout.listener", "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\LogoutListener")
        ->addArgument(new Reference( "security.context" ) )
        ->addArgument(new Reference( "http.utils" ) )
        ->addArgument(new Reference( "default.success.logout.handler" ) );

    $this->container->register("security.context.listener", "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener")
        ->addArgument(new Reference( "security.context" ) )
        ->addArgument( [ new Reference("provider.inmemory") ] )
        ->addArgument( "secured" )
        ->addArgument( new Reference( "monologger.security" ))
        ->addArgument( new Reference("symfony.event.dispatcher") );

    $this->container->register("security.username_password_form.listener", "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener")
        ->addArgument(new Reference( "security.context" ) )
        ->addArgument(new Reference( "authentication.provider.manager" ) )
        ->addArgument(new Reference( "session.strategy.authentication" ) )
        ->addArgument(new Reference( "http.utils" ) )
        ->addArgument("secured")
        ->addArgument(new Reference( "default.success.authentication.handler" ))
        ->addArgument(new Reference( "default.failure.authentication.handler" ))
        ->addArgument([])
        ->addArgument(new Reference( "monologger.security" ))
        ->addArgument(new Reference( "symfony.event.dispatcher" ));

    $this->container->register("security.access.listener", "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\AccessListener")
        ->addArgument(new Reference( "security.context" ) )
        ->addArgument(new Reference( "authorization.access_decision.manager" ) )
        ->addArgument(new Reference( "security.accessmap" ) )
        ->addArgument(new Reference( "authentication.provider.manager" ) );

    $listeners = [
        new Reference("security.channel.listener"),
        new Reference("security.logout.listener"),
        new Reference("security.context.listener"),
        new Reference( "security.username_password_form.listener" ),
        new Reference( "security.access.listener" ),
        new Reference("security.anonymous.listener")
    ];
    ##

    ###Handlers
    $this->container->register( "default.success.logout.handler","Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\DefaultLogoutSuccessHandler")
        ->addArgument( new Reference("http.utils"))
        ->addArgument("/login");

    $this->container->register( "default.failure.authentication.handler","Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler" )
        ->addArgument( new Reference( "http.kernel" ))
        ->addArgument( new Reference( "http.utils" ))
        ->addArgument( [] )
        ->addArgument( new Reference( "monologger.security" ) );

    $this->container->register( "default.success.authentication.handler","Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler")
        ->addArgument( new Reference( "http.utils" ))
        ->addArgument( [] );        

    $this->container->register( "security.firewall.map","Symfony\Component\Security\Http\FirewallMap")
        ->addMethodCall("add", [new Reference("backend.requestmatcher"), $listeners, new Reference("security.exception.listener") ] );

    $this->container->register( "security.firewall","Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall")
        ->addArgument( new Reference("security.firewall.map") )
        ->addArgument( new Reference("symfony.event.dispatcher") );
```